# Change color of custom icon in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

I am registering custom icon with:

```
addCustomMaterialIcon(name: string, url: string) {
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        name,
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`${url}`)
      );
}
```

and using it with

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="vl-icon" class="y-icon" color="primary"></mat-icon>
```

But the icon is white and not seen. How can I change its color? 
Tried with css no luck:

```
.y-icon svg {
  fill: yellowgreen!important;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `::ng-deep`.

```
 ::ng-deep .y-icon {
    fill: yellowgreen !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use **::ng-deep** but it depreciated now instead of that you have to look at **:host-context**

```
::ng-deep .y-icon {
  fill: yellowgreen !important;
}
```

for more details - https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to change the color of `mat-icon svgIcon`

**HTML**

- set `mat-` prefix in your CSS but ignore it when assigning it to the `color` attribute.

  ```
  <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up" color="y-icon"></mat-icon>
  ```

**CSS**

```
.mat-y-icon  {
  color: yellowgreen;
}
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-taqtkq?embed=1&file=app/icon-svg-example.css

Comment: it still not changing color with path fill. the only solution found yet is to convert img svg with script.

Comment: Please note, my solution is using `color` and not `fill`